# Suggest a decent distro for an 10+ year old laptop

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, software-recommendation

I own an [older model laptop](http://www.toshiba.ca/productdetailpage.aspx?id=5650) and I'm finally ready to jump ship to linux, a quick google search and I downloaded puppy (hated it) and downloaded Lubuntu 16.04 and it won't boot on my laptop at all, won't pass the boot selection menu!

I need a lightweight distro that looks good and won't eat up my resources to replace Windows XP on my laptop. I can boost the RAM from 512 to 1 GB but that's as much as I can go.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to Linux!
Researching your specific issue it turns out that Lubuntu doesn't work well with your laptp's processor! It takes a bit of patching and you are a novice user so I don't want to complicate things for you.
I highly recommend you take the RAM upgrade, and I will advice you to use Xubuntu or Linux Mint with mate interface.

The link for [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) is: 
And [Linux mint 18 32 bit](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=219) is

Take a look at the screenshots, and if you have a decent connection download them both and see which one you like from the live session.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am downloading them both, I have a good connection, salams!

Comment: Alright, tell me what you think! I'm here to help you.

Comment: I love how Mint -Sara- looks like, installing it now as we speak! Thank you!